# Core Image autoAdjustmentFilters are not detecting red eye

Tags: ios5, core-image

I'm using the new Core Image APIs in iOS 5 that do auto enhancements. However, the array returned from autoAdjustmentFilters or autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions never removes red eye, it only returns filters such as CIFaceBalance, CIVibrance, and CIHighlightsAndShadows. I've even tried setting the autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions dictionary key kCIImageAutoAdjustRedEye to TRUE, even though the docs state it's true by default. I know the Camera/Photos app will detect red eye on the same image, so something's amiss.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the CIRedEyeCorrections.  Since I do not have any pictures with real red eye.  I just google and found this one "redeye_incorrect_lg.jpg".  This is the first female picture returned from google images.  I found that not all red eye images can be detected.... so make sure yours is real red eye...

```
-(void) coreImageInit
{
    NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *file1 = [sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/redeye_incorrect_lg.jpg"];
    UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:file1]autorelease];
    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:img]; 
    NSLog(@"after ciimage: %@", kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance];
    NSLog(@"options: %@", options);
    NSArray *adjustments = [image autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions:options];
    NSLog(@"adjustments: %@  ", adjustments);

}
```

Here is the my log output that show it detected red eye:

```
11/4/11 10:13:19.231 AM iPadTestBed: after ciimage: kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance
11/4/11 10:13:19.232 AM iPadTestBed: options: {
    kCIImageAutoAdjustEnhance = NO;
}
11/4/11 10:13:19.879 AM iPadTestBed: adjustments: (
    "<CIRedEyeCorrections: inputImage=<CIImage: 0x878a980 extent [0 0 370 427]> inputCameraModel=nil inputCorrectionInfo=(\n        {\n        averageSkinLuminance = 0;\n        bitmaskThreshold = \"0.1372549\";\n        bitmaskX = \"0.372973\";\n        bitmaskY = \"0.5854801\";\n        cornealReflectionThreshold = \"0.854902\";\n        cornealReflectionX = \"0.3783784\";\n        cornealReflectionY = \"0.587822\";\n        existingPupilAverage = \"0.1607843\";\n        existingPupilHigh = \"0.345098\";\n        existingPupilLow = \"0.01176471\";\n        existingPupilMedium = \"0.1333333\";\n        finalEyeCase = 0;\n        forceCase = 0;\n        fullImageHeight = 427;\n        fullImageWidth = 370;\n        imageOrientation = 1;\n        imageSignalToNoiseRatio = 20;\n        imageSpecialValue = 0;\n        interocularDistance = \"0.2284475\";\n        pointX = \"0.3702703\";\n        pointY = \"0.587822\";\n        pupilShadeAlignment = 1;\n        pupilShadeAverage = \"0.2117647\";\n        pupilShadeHigh = \"0.2901961\";\n        pupilShadeLow = \"0.1372549\";\n        pupilShadeMedium = \"0.2117647\";\n        repairRectangleMaximumX = \"0.4162162\";\n        repairRectangleMaximumY = \"0.557377\";\n        repairRectangleMinimumX = \"0.3513514\";\n        repairRectangleMinimumY = \"0.6135831\";\n        searchRectangleMaximumX = \"0.4864865\";\n        searchRectangleMaximumY = \"0.4871194\";\n        searchRectangleMinimumX = \"0.2540541\";\n        searchRectangleMinimumY = \"0.6885245\";\n        size = \"0.012472\";\n        snappedX = \"0.3702703\";\n        snappedY = \"0.587822\";\n    },\n        {\n        averageSkinLuminance = 0;\n        bitmaskThreshold = \"0.09411766\";\n        bitmaskX = \"0.7081081\";\n        bitmaskY = \"0.6533958\";\n        cornealReflectionThreshold = \"0.8745099\";\n        cornealReflectionX = \"0.7081081\";\n        cornealReflectionY = \"0.6487119\";\n        existingPupilAverage = \"0.1686275\";\n        existingPupilHigh = \"0.3490196\";\n        existingPupilLow = \"0.03921569\";\n        existingPupilMedium = \"0.1372549\";\n        finalEyeCase = 0;\n        forceCase = 0;\n        fullImageHeight = 427;\n        fullImageWidth = 370;\n        imageOrientation = 1;\n        imageSignalToNoiseRatio = 20;\n        imageSpecialValue = 0;\n        interocularDistance = \"0.2284475\";\n        pointX = \"0.7081081\";\n        pointY = \"0.6557377\";\n        pupilShadeAlignment = 1;\n        pupilShadeAverage = \"0.2117647\";\n        pupilShadeHigh = \"0.2901961\";\n        pupilShadeLow = \"0.1372549\";\n        pupilShadeMedium = \"0.2117647\";\n        repairRectangleMaximumX = \"0.7405406\";\n        repairRectangleMaximumY = \"0.6229508\";\n        repairRectangleMinimumX = \"0.6864865\";\n        repairRectangleMinimumY = \"0.6697892\";\n        searchRectangleMaximumX = \"0.827027\";\n        searchRectangleMaximumY = \"0.5526932\";\n        searchRectangleMinimumX = \"0.5945946\";\n        searchRectangleMinimumY = \"0.7540984\";\n        size = \"0.010893\";\n        snappedX = \"0.7081081\";\n        snappedY = \"0.6557377\";\n    }\n)>"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. I did notice on that image it worked. The issue I guess I've had is the same images which will have red eye removed in the Photos app will not always return CIRedEyeCorrections using autoAdjustmentFiltersWithOptions.